# PySpark - Add rows to dataframe based on date column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to add rows to a dataframe based on the date of row.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(0, 0, 0, '2023-03-03'), (1, 1, 1, '2023-03-04'), (2, 2, 2, '2023-03-05')], ['item_id', 'action_id', 'status', 'date'])
df.show()

+-------+---------+------+----------+
|item_id|action_id|status|      date|
+-------+---------+------+----------+
|      0|        0|     0|2023-03-03|
|      1|        1|     1|2023-03-04|
|      2|        2|     2|2023-03-05|
+-------+---------+------+----------+
```

For each existing row, I need to add 3 more duplicate rows, but with each date increasing by 7 days.

I imagine I'll need to use `explode`, and `array_repeat`, but I am confused.

I'm expecting this resulting table:

```
+-------+---------+------+----------+
|item_id|action_id|status|      date|
+-------+---------+------+----------+
|      0|        0|     0|2023-03-03|
|      0|        0|     0|2023-03-10|
|      0|        0|     0|2023-03-17|
|      0|        0|     0|2023-03-24|
|      1|        1|     1|2023-03-04|
|      1|        1|     1|2023-03-11|
|      1|        1|     1|2023-03-18|
|      1|        1|     1|2023-03-25|
|      2|        2|     2|2023-03-05|
|      2|        2|     2|2023-03-12|
|      2|        2|     2|2023-03-19|
|      2|        2|     2|2023-03-26|
+-------+---------+------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do this, is by using the `sequence` and the `explode` functions from `pyspark.sql.functions`.

Let's start creating your dataframe, just like you did:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (0, 0, 0, '2023-03-03'),
        (1, 1, 1, '2023-03-04'),
        (2, 2, 2, '2023-03-05')
    ],
    ['item_id', 'action_id', 'status', 'date']
)
```

Then you can use the aforementioned functions:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

output = df \
    .withColumn(
        "date",
        F.sequence(
            F.to_date(df.date),
            F.to_date(df.date + F.expr("INTERVAL 21 DAYS")),
            F.expr("INTERVAL 7 DAYS")
        )
    ) \
    .withColumn(
        "date",
        F.explode(F.col("date"))
    )
```

The `sequence` function has the following arguments:

- start (the original `date` column)
- end (the original `date` column + 21 days, since you want 3 weeks extra)
- interval (in this case, 7 days)

And then using `explode` we flatten the array columns to multiple single element rows.

And our output is:

```
>>> output.show()
+-------+---------+------+----------+
|item_id|action_id|status|      date|
+-------+---------+------+----------+
|      0|        0|     0|2023-03-03|
|      0|        0|     0|2023-03-10|
|      0|        0|     0|2023-03-17|
|      0|        0|     0|2023-03-24|
|      1|        1|     1|2023-03-04|
|      1|        1|     1|2023-03-11|
|      1|        1|     1|2023-03-18|
|      1|        1|     1|2023-03-25|
|      2|        2|     2|2023-03-05|
|      2|        2|     2|2023-03-12|
|      2|        2|     2|2023-03-19|
|      2|        2|     2|2023-03-26|
+-------+---------+------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a way using `array_repeat` and `transform`. `array_repeat` to create an array of the same date. [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform.html#pyspark-sql-functions-transform) to add the number of days to each element - note that it accepts a binary lambda function where the second argument is 0-based index.

example

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('date_arr', 
               func.expr('transform(array_repeat(date, 3), (x, i) -> date_add(x, i*7))')
               ). \
    selectExpr(*data_sdf.drop('date').columns, 'explode(date_arr) as date'). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +-------+---------+------+----------+
# |item_id|action_id|status|date      |
# +-------+---------+------+----------+
# |0      |0        |0     |2023-03-03|
# |0      |0        |0     |2023-03-10|
# |0      |0        |0     |2023-03-17|
# |1      |1        |1     |2023-03-04|
# |1      |1        |1     |2023-03-11|
# |1      |1        |1     |2023-03-18|
# |2      |2        |2     |2023-03-05|
# |2      |2        |2     |2023-03-12|
# |2      |2        |2     |2023-03-19|
# +-------+---------+------+----------+
```